# Cygwin: cygstart * Not Opening All Files

Tags: bash, file, cygwin

One thing that I really don't like with Cygwin is when I have to open files one by one. I set up an alias of opening files (instead of cygstart, I use open). However, everytime I want to open up multiple files, say a pdf, it will only open the first file in the directory. Here is what I type:

```
open *
open *.pdf
cygstart *
cygstart *.pdf
```

None of these work. However when I do something like `mv *` or `cp *` it works. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` will expand to all files in the current directory.

For example:

```
$ ls
1.pdf  2.pdf  3.pdf
```

In this case `*` will expand to `1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf`. If you give this as a parameter to an other command, then it will see 3 separate parameter. Many program can handle this, but apparently `open` and `cygstart` can handle only the first parameter.

To solve this problem this script should be added to a directory which is found in your PATH environment variable (e.g: `c:\cygwin\bin`):

**myopen.sh:**

```
for i in "$@"; do
  cygstart "$i"
done
```

After that it can be called like this:

```
myopen.sh *.pdf
```